# Visual state fade in and fade out?

Tags: c#, silverlight, code-behind

Currently I have a set of visual states defined which fade in paths, here's an example:

```
<VisualState x:Name="MyPathFadeIn">
  <Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPath" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" From="#00000000" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1.5" />
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Now I was wondering, is there a way to automatically call some sort of fade out state if I change the current visual state from codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual states are all about state! In your code behind you can set your control to a state via the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method. So, if you want to 'call' some fade-out state, just set the control to that state!

Comment: oh right, so I'll have to explicitly set a fade out state then... was hoping for an automated method but that's definitely fair enough given it is in effect a system using states.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but when you're using a `ColorAnimation` I'm quite sure you don't have to set the `ColorAnimation.From` property.  If you leave it unset, then the Transition to the visual state should start from the colour that it is currently set as.
As such, if you define the storyboards with just `ColorAnimation.To` properties, it may help in having to explicitly declare everything?

Alternatively, you could always extend the `VisualStateManger` with your own subclass.  One that sets all the other `VisualStateGroups` to 'Off' when it receives a new state change?